# Creating a new folder or pasting a file into shared network folder macOS asks for username and password

Tags: finder, network, password, sharing, file-sharing

I am using macOS and facing an issue when trying to create a new folder or pasting a file into the particular folder located on a shared network server.

A popup window occurs and asks for a username and password.

Message;
"Finder wants to copy file enter an administrator name and password to allow this"

My steps:

1. Pressed <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>K</kbd>
2. Enter service IP: `smb:\\192.168.2.150`
3. Enter credentials: (username and password)
4. Select library/folder.
5. Went to the folder location.
6. Trying to create a new folder or paste a file.
7. A popup window with the message as mentioned above.

I tried to put the same credentials again but it's not working.

Although I can access and copy files from the same folder as well as can create folder copy/paste items on other folders located on the same server without any issue and that's working fine.

Only the problem is with this particular folder when pasting files and creating new folders.

Folder location: `server_ip/folder/2022/March`

Note: the server is using Windows os.

Can anyone please help me out?